# JQuery Autocomplete IE8 (Web Service ASMX))

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services, internet-explorer-8

Please Help!

I am trying to use a Web Service (ASMX) file.  When i view this and query it the page returns exactly what I want.  So that page seems to be fine.

The issue is I'm trying to add an auto-complete to a textbox in my ASP.NET application but it doesn't seem to be doing anything!  I've included all the relevant JQuery files (jquery-ui.js, jquery-ui-css, query-1-11.2.min.js)  in my Site.master file.

Within my page i've included the Javascript to do the autocomplete.

Can anyone point my in the right direction?  I'm still using IE8...

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtAutoFill').autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'UserList.asmx/GetAutoCompleteData',
                    method: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    //data: JSON.stringify({ username: request.username }),
                    data: request.username,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContentPH" runat="server">
    <h1 id="h01"></h1>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAutoFill" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check. Even though your text box id is "txtAutoFill" at the server side, it may include the container id when the actual page is generated (i.e. Content2_txtAutoFill). If that is the case, view page source in the browser and change your id within your javascript to match that. Also please see [Understanding and implementing jQuery autocomplete with AJAX source and appendTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729588/understanding-and-implementing-jquery-autocomplete-with-ajax-source-and-appendto)

Answer (score 0):

Add ClientIDMode="Static" to your TextBox control

```
<asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtAutoFill" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```